# Mutually exclusive Enum controlled by a EnumSet

Tags: java, enumset

```
public enum TagEnum {
   MALE,FEMALE,//GENDER
   YOUNG,MIDDLE_AGED,OLD//AGE
}
```

I wanna use TagEnum to describe a Person.
MALE and FEMALE are mutually exclusive,
so are those enums for age.

For example, once you put MALE into the EnumSet, FEMALE will not be accepted.

Is there such a EnumSet?

==update==

Note that both of gender and age are used to describe a person. What's going on if I have more then 5 dimensions? To make 5 enums and 5 separate references?

**Since I need a test method to know if someone own such an enum, it's redundant to make 5 overloaded methods like this:**

```
boolean test(Age age);
boolean test(Gender gender);
boolean test(OtherDimension other);
//What a pity Enum can't be inherited
```

Is there a way to make it easier? Thanks!

Comment: So are all the elements of this enum exclusive? Are you looking for an `EnumSet` which can't contain more than one element?

Comment: That's called "a single instance of an enum" :-)

Comment: Does every `TagEnum` have one mutually exclusive `TagEnum`?

Comment: No, Not all of them are exclusive. I've updated the question. @SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I want. @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: @Anderson You have a problem in your data modeling. You should make two enums, one called `Gender` and one called `Age`. That's why you have a strange requirement for the Set. You just need two attributes in wherever you are refering to gender and age, one reference to an instance of `Gender` and one reference to an instance of `Age`.

Comment: This sounds like an architectural problem - you really need 2 enums: One for age, and one for gender. This will naturally enforce your need for exclusivity.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Note that both of them are used to describe a person. What's going on if I have more than 5 dimensions? To make 5 enums and 5 separate references? Since I need a test method to know if someone own such an enum, it's redundant to make 5 methods again.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie What about more then 5 enums? I've updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: You'll just be shifting the complexity into your `EnumSet`. Multiple overloads will be a lot simpler to maintain than a special set of rules around enum combinations. I'd go with the overloads.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. `EnumSet`, and `Set` more generally, is not the correct data structure for this.

Why do you think you need a `Set` in the first place? If all you want is mutual exclusivity, a single reference to a `TagEnum` will suffice.

Comment: Sorry, NOT all of them are exclusive. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

`EnumSet` is not an immutable `Set`, and it DO have methods like `add` and `remove`. It has numbers of `Enum` values after initialized. And you can `add` or `remove` other `Enum` values of same type with the initialization.
Besides, the way of initializing an `EnumSet` is like this:

```
EnumSet<TagEnum> all = EnumSet.allOf(TagEnum.class);
EnumSet<TagEnum> none = EnumSet.noneOf(TagEnum.class);
EnumSet<TagEnum> range = EnumSet.range(TagEnum.MALE, TagEnum.FEMALE);
EnumSet<TagEnum> some = EnumSet.of(TagEnum.YOUNG,TagEnum.OLD);
```

Meanwhile, you can handle EnumSet like this:

```
for(TagEnum a : all){
    System.out.println(a);
}        
if(all.contains(TagEnum.MALE)){
    System.out.println("sure");
}
```

Hope these will help you.

Comment: `EnumSet` is not an immutable `Set`, and it DO have methods like `add` and `remove`.

Comment: @MattBall@Anderson check [here](http://man.lupaworld.com/content/develop/JDK_6.0_API_html_zh_CN/html/zh_CN/api/java/util/class-use/EnumSet.html).

Comment: @SilentKnight We can't read mandarin. Here's the [Javadoc in English](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html). EnumSet implements `Set` so of course it has methods `add` and `remove`. They are required for any implementation of `Set`.

Comment: @Anderson @ErwinBolwidt Hahaha, Feel sorry when realizeing my providing a Url linking to a Chinese webpage. And you are right, I think I missed `Methods inherited from interface java.util.Set`.